# What are the minimum prerequisites to understand queueing theory?

Tags: soft-question, self-learning, queueing-theory, learning

I have limited mathematical ability, never did calculus and only a tiny bit of linear algebra. Most mathematical notation is lost on me. What are the minimum prerequisite topics that I can familiarize myself with in order for queueing theory and queue networks to be accessible to me?

Comment: Basic analysis on the limiting behavior of the $M/M/1$ queue uses infinite series, so that is one place to start...